# How to write integer values to a file using out.write()?

Tags: python, file-io

I am generating some numbers (let's say, `num`) and writing the numbers to an output file using `outf.write(num).`

But the interpreter is throwing an error:

```
    outf.write(num)  
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not int.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Would you post the declaration of outf?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus `outf = open('outdata.txt', 'w')` guessing from the context (and of course the filename is made up :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[write()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=write#file.write) only takes a *single string* argument, so you could do this:

```
outf.write(str(num))
```

or

```
outf.write('{}'.format(num))  # more "modern"
outf.write('%d' % num)        # deprecated mostly
```

Also note that `write` will not append a newline to your output so if you need it you'll have to supply it yourself.

**Aside**:

Using string formatting would give you more control over your output, so for instance you could write (both of these are equivalent):

```
num = 7
outf.write('{:03d}\n'.format(num))

num = 12
outf.write('%03d\n' % num)
```

to get three spaces, with leading zeros for your integer value followed by a newline:

```
007
012
```

[format()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) will be around for a long while, so it's worth learning/knowing.

Comment: Don't worry, I got confused. It's the usage of `%` that requires a tuple for more than one parameter, not `format()`.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "modern"? (If you clarify/change the answer, I'll delete this comment so the comments don't get messy)

Comment: @MechtEngineer Simply that using the format function is the more preferred way of formatting text over printf-like formatting in Python nowadays (I use both, probably printf slightly more, since I use it in Java, C, etc too). HTH

Answer (score 4):

any of these should work

```
outf.write("%s" % num)

outf.write(str(num))

print >> outf, num
```

Comment: And two of these are deprecated.

Comment: @BlaXpirit One and a half, because % format is going to be here for long

Answer (score 2):

```
i = Your_int_value
```

Write bytes value like this for example:

```
the_file.write(i.to_bytes(2,"little"))
```

Depend of you int value size and the bit order your prefer

Comment: to_bytes(...) method  "New in version 3.2."

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use f-string formatting to write integer to file

For appending use following code, for writing once replace 'a' with 'w'.

```py
for i in s_list:
    with open('path_to_file','a') as file:
        file.write(f'{i}\n')

file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open ('file1.txt','a') ##you can also write here 'w' for create or writing into file
while True :
    no = int(input("enter a number (0 for exit)"))
    if no == 0 :
        print("you entered zero(0) ....... \nnow you are exit  !!!!!!!!!!!")
        break
    else :
        f.write(str(no)+"\n")

f.close()
   
f1 = open ('Ass1.txt','r')

print("\n content of file :: \n",f1.read())

f1.close()
```