# How to write a counter to an output file in Python?

Tags: python

This is the code I have so far. Is there no way to write it aside from convert it to a string?

```
outfile = input("What would you like the text file index's name to be?")

if os.path.isfile(outfile):
    print("Name already used, please choose another")
else:
    fp = open(outfile, 'w')
    fp.write(count)
    fp.write(wordCount)
    fp.close
```

The error I'm getting says that it must be a string to write to an output file. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try type casting to string write(str(count)) and write(str(wordCount)).

Comment: what count is storing, is ti variable or you just wnat to write count to file???, as i cant see count decleared before??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write integer values to a file using out.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160939/how-to-write-integer-values-to-a-file-using-out-write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only pass strings as arguments to `file.write`, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write).
Here's how you could implement it:

```
with open(outfile, "w") as fp:
    fp.write(str(count))
    fp.write(str(wordcount))
```

Note `str()` around `count`. This function converts an object to a string, see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) page for more info.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(outfile, "w") as fp:
    fp.write(str(count))
    fp.write(str(wordcount))
```

Answer (score -2):

try `fp.write("count")`

write function takes only string and string are in the quotes and 'count' is not the integer also that is why you are getting the error while running the code.